# Encoding/Decoding base64 decodedData = nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64, nsdata

Yesterday I wrote a working code for this, but I erased it and when writing a new one something is really weird:

I encode it a picture this way:

```
let pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture!)
let pictureToString64 = pictureData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

(I had JPEGRepresentation before, but it wasn't working, so I tried with JPEG)
and I decode this way by getting `pic 64` which I believe it has the correct value. It starts with `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAA`(...)

```
 let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: pic64, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
 let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
 let pictureDataLocal = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(decodedImage!, 100)
                defaults.setObject(pictureDataLocal, forKey: "profilePicture")
```

**The problem is that decodedData is always nil.** Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has to do with `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions`.

Using `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters` instead of `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)`, I was able to decode the Base64 encoded string back into `NSData`, and created a `UIImage` from that data:

```
let picture = UIImage(named: "myImage")

let pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture!)

let pictureToString64 = pictureData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: pictureToString64!, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
let pictureDataLocal = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(decodedImage!, 100)
```

`NSDataBase64DecodingOptions` inherits from `OptionSetType` which is why you get the rawValue initializer.  It is better to use the one of the set types, rather passing in a value.  I saw in the header that `NSDataBase64DecodingOptions` was the only public var in the struct, so I tried it.

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public struct NSDataBase64DecodingOptions : OptionSetType {
    public init(rawValue: UInt)

    // Use the following option to modify the decoding algorithm so that it ignores unknown non-Base64 bytes, including line ending characters.
    public static var IgnoreUnknownCharacters: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions { get }
}
```

Comment: `rawValue` can be used, however, since it's a `BitwiseOperationsType` using it without an element type set will return nil. If the rawValue actually has a value (eg. 1), then it should work.

Comment: @PauloMartins You're welcome!  If my solution has helped you don't forget to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show others that it has helped.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JAL I won't forget it when I got 15 reputation :)

Comment: @PauloMartins Accepting is different than upvoting.  You can accept at any reputation level, and you get two rep points yourself for doing so.